# Adding parameters to a function that is a parameter

Tags: javascript

Don't know how to explain this propperly, but basically I have:

```
mg.postGiApi("Dashboard", "postChartOsTypeData", { groupIdList: that.idList }, function (data) {
    that.tempName(data, "osType", cb);
});
```

And I want it to look like:

```
mg.postGiApi("Dashboard", "postChartOsTypeData", { groupIdList: that.idList }, that.tempName.someExtendingFunction("osType", cb));
```

Where I am looking for "someExtendingFunction" that lets me do this. Is this possible at all? Not a huge deal, but would clean things up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native function that does this, but you could write a similar function:

```
function someExtendingFunction(context, name, type, cb) {
    return function(data) {
        context[name].call(context, data, type, cb);
    };
}

mg.postGiApi("Dashboard",
             "postChartOsTypeData",
             { groupIdList: that.idList },
             someExtendingFunction(that, "tempName", "osType", cb));
```

Notice that `that.tempName.someExtendingFunction(…)` will never work, as the `that` context would be lost. If you call `someExtendingFunction` as a (`Function.prototype`) method on the method, you will need to supply the context explicitly, like [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does it.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `bind` as in `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
mg.postGiApi("Dashboard", "postChartOsTypeData", { groupIdList: that.idList }, that.tempName.someExtendingFunction.bind(null, "osType", cb));
```

This will only work in ECMAScript 5 compatible browsers. If you want something supported by older browsers, you can use underscore.js and use its `_.bind` function.

```
mg.postGiApi("Dashboard", "postChartOsTypeData", { groupIdList: that.idList }, _.bind(that.tempName.someExtendingFunction, null, "osType", cb));
```

This will return a function that will be called with the arguments you pass on to it.

`null` refers to the `this` of that variable.

You can read more about `bind` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Not exactly. `data` is the first parameter, not the last.

Comment: You also forgot to pass `that` as the context. With `null` it probably won't work.